# VS Code: local variables not showing correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I don't get the previous given answers. I'm new to VS Code and know a bit of c++ coding. I tried the tutorial for windows/mingw :
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_step-through-the-code
and done everything so far. The sample code has been build and I want to debug now, but my variables view is showing something different when stepping through the application when debugging. (see attached image)
[image]
The word should contain any of the strings, as well as msg should show something different. My watch for a self made i int shows correctly, though. Whats'up? I did everything as in the tutorial.

also: the terminal tab does not output the msg from cout, but I see it in the debug console instead. (see image in tutorial just above the chapter 'set a watch')

launch.json is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        

        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Aktive Datei erstellen und debuggen",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Automatische Strukturierung und Einrückung für \"gdb\" aktivieren",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

sorry, i'm a newb to vs code :-/

Comment: What is the output of `-exec info pretty-printer` in the debug console?

Comment: The debug console shows: 
[...]
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
=cmd-param-changed,param="args",value="2>CON 1>CON <CON"
[New Thread 17228.0x4e20]
[New Thread 17228.0x1614]
[New Thread 17228.0x4bbc]
[New Thread 17228.0x35c8]
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
[...]
Loaded 'C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Execute debugger commands using "-exec <command>", for example [...]

Comment: I think it's solved: I re-installed using the 64bit version of MinGW as I had an old 32 bit version running via mingw-get. Now everything looks nice. Was not believing it had to do with mingw as it ran under eclipse (which I'm installing as a comparison IDE).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/how-to-enable-gdb-pretty-printing-for-c-stl-objects-in-eclipse-cdt

Answer (score 3):

I re-installed using the 64bit version of MinGW from sourceforge as I had an old 32 bit version running via mingw-get.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that pretty-printing did not display UTF-8 content correctly. You can either:

1. Set it to UTF-8 charset ([VSCode debugger having issues with character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991808/vscode-debugger-having-issues-with-character-encoding))
2. Disable pretty-printing ([Cannot see any variable values while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964084/cannot-see-any-variable-values-while-debugging))